# calling another activity android manifest xml

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have two sperate applications and I want to call start an activity from the second application in the first, here is my code to do so :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.two.three.application","org.two.three.application.one));
Context H= context;
H.startActivity(intent1);
```

And in the android manifest of the project I have this code, I have the line :

```
<activity android:name=".one">
    </activity>
```

But I keep getting a runtime error, logcat says :

> "Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {org.two.three.application/org.two.three.application.one}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Can anyone see my error? The only thing I can think of is my package of the first activity is `org.two.three.Class` while the second is `org.two.three.application.SecondClass`. Does this matter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At first try removing those code that you are adding

**

```
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.two.three.application","org.two.three.application.one));
Context H= context;
```

**

**Then  add following code into an action method like onClick**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);


Add your Android Manifest configuration file



   <activity android:name="NewActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: I'm getting a cannot find symbol error on the line "Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);" and i have edited the values to match my own code

Comment: NewActivity.class instead your Activity

Comment: So it would be MyActivity.class?

Comment: This is first Activity and NewActivity is second activity

Comment: I am still getting the same error, do i not need to provide a path to the package?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your activity publicly available. To do that just add

```
android:exported="true"
```

to the `<activity>` tag in your manifest.

Normally, activities are not available to other components that are outside of the package. This is the standard default behaviour. But, of course, you can make them available if you want to.